# org.apache.poi.POIXMLException Strict OOXML isn't currently supported, please see bug #57699

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'd like to parse an Excel file with java, so I'm using apache poi libraries, here you are the maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
```

This will include a series of dependencies:

```
poi-ooxml-3.14.jar
poi-3.14.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
curvesapi-1.03.jar
```

When I try to read an Office 365 Excel file (.xslx) with this code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class ExcelConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String excelFilePath = "C:/temp/Book1.xlsx";
        File myFile = new File(excelFilePath);
        System.out.println("File exists: " + myFile.exists());
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
   }
}
```

I got the following console message:

```
File exists: true
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: Strict OOXML isn't currently supported, please see bug #57699
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.getPartFromOPCPackage(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:679)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.<init>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:122)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.<init>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:115)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.<init>(POIXMLDocument.java:61)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:273)
    at org.myCompany.excel.ExcelConverter.main(ExcelConverter.java:25)
```

Do you know what can I do to solve the issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The only option would be to invest the time required to add support for this format, but it is likely no small undertaking, if you want to spend some time to bring it forward it is probably best to post on the bug-entry mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 20):

There doesn't currently appear to be any simple solution other than "Don't save your spreadsheet in "strict OOXML" format."

For example, in Excel use

```
Save As --> "Excel Workbook (.xlsx)"
```

instead of

```
Save As --> "Strict Open XML Spreadsheet (.xlsx)"
```

---

> Do you know why Excel Worksheet and this format have the same file extension?

That would be something that only Microsoft can answer.  But I guess that the engineers (or their management) did not *anticipate* that it would be necessary for application software to make the distinction.

> I am accepting Files as input and then processing them based on the extension. How can I know without try-catch?

There is nothing that will let you process the document with current generation POI.

I guess you could code something to read the file and look for the signature for "strict OOXML" format<sup>1</sup> before passing the file to POI, but there's not much point.  You would be writing a stack of extra code just so that you can replace the try-catch with other logic.

---

<sup>1 - See https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000395.shtml#sign</sup>

Comment: In my Excel (for Office 3"65 MSO (16.0.12527.20260) 32-bit, that means Save As --> "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)" near the top of the menu, not Save As --> "Strict Open XML Spreadsheet (*.xlsx)" near the bottom of the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

I use a slightly modified version of @PJFanning's ooxml converter https://github.com/pjfanning/ooxml-strict-converter to check for and convert strict Excel files and then read them with POI. In limited testing it seems to work, although the files I have are pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the file as Excel Workbook (.xlsx) worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

The `excel-streaming-reader` library has a beta feature now for converting from Strict OOXML by setting the flag `convertFromOoXmlStrict` in the `StreamingReader` builder:

https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader/blob/aaf05d058c8e969e9737d27e6844b4a7d32f6fe6/src/main/java/com/github/pjfanning/xlsx/StreamingReader.java#L245

Comment: excel-streaming-reader v3.0.3 now supports strict format xlsx files with using the convertFromOoXmlStrict setting