# Apache POI 4.1 - new XSSFWorkbook causes POIXMLException: Strict OOXML isn't currently supported

Tags: openxlsx

I am aware that about 3-4 years ago, there was an issue(bug #57699) with reading .xlsx file ([org.apache.poi.POIXMLException Strict OOXML isn't currently supported, please see bug #57699](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749841/org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-strict-ooxml-isnt-currently-supported-please-se))

Today I tried Apache POI 4.1, I still see bug #57699 with the following 1 line of code:

```java
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(uploadFile.getInputStream());
```

The exception message is below:

> org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: Strict OOXML isn't currently supported, please see bug #57699

Is there any workaround solution with bug #57699 beside using different format?

Thank you greatly for help!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749841/org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-strict-ooxml-isnt-currently-supported-please-se